# Column value replace in data frame pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a data frame as below

|  | datetime | vnum | seq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11-03-2021 22:05 | APD 202613 | 867 |
| 2 | 11-03-2021 22:08 | AHD 152425 | 869 |
| 3 | 11-03-2021 22:10 |  |  |
| 4 | 11-03-2021 22:12 |  |  |
| 5 | 11-03-2021 22:15 | APD 202647 | 875 |
| 6 | 11-03-2021 22:18 | APD 202702 | 877 |
| 7 | 11-03-2021 22:22 | AHD 152540 | 881 |
| 8 | 15-03-2021 07:03 | **D 154070** | 177 |

```
|  #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype          |
|---------------------------------------------------|
|  0   datetime      non-null        datetime64[ns] |
|  1   vnum          non-null        object         |
|  2   seq           non-null        object         |
```

1. In Some rows the column 'vnum' is blank/ one space or 8 char
   Requirement: if value less than 10 char replace it with 'XXX 000000'
2. In Some rows the column 'seq' has same issue like column 'vnum'
   Generally seq column value ranges from 1~1300
   Requirement1: if value say '51' make it '0051' - add prefix 0 to make it 4 digit
   Requirement2: value blank/space make it '0000'

I tired with below codes, but it's is not replacing  with 'XXX 000000' , the entire column gets replaced or nothing happens.

```
df[df['vnum'] == ''] = 'XXX 000000'
df['vnum'] = df['vnum'].replace([' ', ''], 'XXX 000000')
df['vnum']=df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True) 
df[['seq']] = df[['seq']].fillna('9999')
df['seq'] = df['seq'].str.zfill(4)
df['seq'] = pd.to_numeric(df['seq'], downcast='signed')
```

Comment: What is `print (df['vnum'].head(5).tolist())` ?

Comment: I ask because not sure if there is empty strings? spaces? or NaNs ?

Comment: @jezrael, it shows something like this  'APD  202646',
 'APD  202613',
 'AHD  152425',
 '\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 '\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 'APD  202647']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First replace in all columns `x00` to empty strings and then use your solution:

```
df = df.replace('\x00', '', regex=True) 

#for replace space or empty strings
df['vnum'] = df['vnum'].replace([' ', ''], 'XXX 000000')
#for replace empty strings or one, two  to n spaces only
df['vnum'] = df['vnum'].replace('^\s*$', 'XXX 000000', regex=True)
df['seq'] = df['seq'].astype(str).str.zfill(4)
```

Comment: @jesrael: how to solve the requirement- if value less than 10 char replace it with 'XXX 000000'. Example row 8 of the given data frame

Comment: @user_v27 - Use `df['vnum'] = df['vnum'].mask(df['vnum'].str.len() < 10, 'XXX 000000')`